# Laravel 4 MethodNotAllowed Exception

Tags: php, laravel-4

Following is my Controller, Route and View File.

Can you please help me to solve this ?

**Route File**

```
Route::controller('account','AccountController' );
Route::controller('course','CourseController' );
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showIndex');
```

**Controller File**

```
<?php

class CourseController extends AuthorizedController
{

    protected $whitelist = array(
        'getCourse',
        'postCourse'
    );

    /**
     * Main users page.
     *
     * @access   public
     * @return   View
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        // Show the page.
        //
        $course = Course::all();


        return View::make('course/create')->with('course', new Course());
    }

    public function postCourse()
    {


        $rules = array(
            'name' => 'Required',
            'has_branch'  => 'Required',
            'status'      => 'Required',
        );


        $inputs = Input::all();

        // Validate the inputs.
        //
        $validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
```

Following is my **View**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

{{-- Web site Title --}}
@section('title')
@parent
:: Account
@stop

{{-- New Laravel 4 Feature in use --}}
@section('styles')
@parent
body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
@stop

{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>New Entery</h1>
</div>
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" id="csrf_token" value="{{{ Session::getToken() }}}" />

    <!-- Course Name -->
    <div class="control-group {{{ $errors->has('name') ? 'error' : '' }}}">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Course Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{{ Request::old('name', $course->name) }}}" />
            {{ $errors->first('name') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ course name -->

    <!-- Status -->
    <div class="control-group {{{ $errors->has('status') ? 'error' : '' }}}">
        <label class="control-label" for="status">Status</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="status" id="status" value="{{{ Request::old('status', $course->status) }}}" />
            {{ $errors->first('status') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ last name -->

    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="control-group {{{ $errors->has('description') ? 'error' : '' }}}">
        <label class="control-label" for="description">Description</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="{{{ Request::old('description', $course->description) }}}" />
            {{ $errors->first('description') }}
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="control-group {{{ $errors->has('has_branch') ? 'error' : '' }}}">
        <label class="control-label" for="has_branch">Has Branch</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="has_branch" id="has_branch" value="" />
            {{ $errors->first('has_branch') }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ password -->
    <!-- Update button -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ update button -->
</form>
@stop
```

When I hit Submit button It gives me:

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Code for AuthorizedController

```
<?php

class AuthorizedController extends BaseController
{
    protected $whitelist = array();

    /**
     * Initializer.
     *
     * @access   public
     * @return \AuthorizedController
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Check if the user is logged in.
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => $this->whitelist));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `AuthorizedController`?

Comment: @markcial , This is my first laravel application I am adding code for AuthorizedController

Answer (score 0):

You don't have path on your form action attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
```

Also I would recommend you to use blade. With blade, you'll have cleaner separation of your logic and you view.

Comment: Please look @ https://github.com/krishnal/Laravel4-Bootsrap, Here account controller is working perfectly it has the same code

Answer (score 0):

You display form on '/'.

This form's method is post.

But it's pointing to the same URL and you don't have POST action for '/' route.
I think what you're trying to do is to post this form to the postCourse action of CourseController.

You need to either add Route::post for '/' or correctly point this form to right method.

Comment: Please look @ https://github.com/krishnal/Laravel4-Bootsrap, Here account controller is working perfectly it has the same code

Comment: But the name of the methods are getIndex and postIndex, here this is not the case... 
Read my answer again

Comment: I am sorry dude i am new in laraval so i am not clear, but postRegister is working in account controller, Is it the same as postCourse in the course controller ? or can you help suggest me solution ?

Comment: I suggest you to fill path attribute in your form.